# How to customize Contact Map popup on clicking on icons?

Tags: contacts

I'm trying to remove the street address right now from the Google Map that's created from Search Contact -> Map Contacts when you click on the people icons placed on the map. This is for privacy purposes, but I'm interested in adding some custom contact info there later.

I researched and found the Mapping Providers are at templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Map. When I copied Google.tpl, renamed to GoogleCityOnly.tpl, and edited - it shows up as a selection in the Mapping and Geocoding system menu for Mapping Providers. But when I choose it and search contacts, the "Map Contact" no longer shows up.

What am I missing to have "Map Contact" show up again? Where's the guidance for making an alternate Mapping Provider?

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 6.35

Answer (score 1):

1. When you select Google as the map provider, I assume the Map Contact shows up.
2. Ensure that When you select GoogleCityOnly, you also retain the Google Map API Key. The code checks for the presence of both a mapping provider and a mapAPIKey before displaying the Map Contact link
3. If you want to "modify" the code to avoid the Map API key for now, check: CRM/Contact/Selector.php and search for mapAPIKey

Comment: Thanks Donald. When I choose Google as map provider, Map Contact does show up. I'm not understanding why the Google Map API Key should make a difference, since it is an empty field. I'm not using it. But I did try deleting the check for the mapAPIKey in Selector.php. That didn't work. I even tried forcing the code to add the item - but it still doesn't show up.

    //if ($config->mapProvider) {
        self::$_links[CRM_Core_Action::MAP] = array(
        <deleted code>
          'title' => ts('Map Contact'),
       );
      //}

Comment: The mini-Markdown didn't work - but the last bit was showing where I commented out "if ($config->mapProvider) {", after deleting "$config->mapAPIKey &&"/

Comment: Ok - one last comment - I think I need guidance about how to copy the Google.tpl file. I'm pretty sure my edit was good, but I tried removing my edits to change the output, and just have GoogleCityOnly.tpl have the exact same content as Google.tpl. I can select "GoogleCityOnly" in System Settings. But "Map Contact" does not appear in the batch choices.